# css position element's top to windows bottom

Tags: css, positioning

I was giving a look to this [page](http://www.capellahotels.com/newyork/about-en.html).I was wondering how is positioned the div containing the navigation menu.
I noticed that even resizing the window it continue to stay at the view's bottom.

How could I achieve the same effect?
thanks

Sarah

Answer (score 1):

This is done with javascript or jQuery. It is **not possible to achieve with CSS only**.

basically, you specify function onresizee(), and calculate appropriate positions.

Everything is very well eyplained on jQuery website.

Comment: i mean wich is the behavior of that div how should I make it behave in my jquery function?

Comment: You can call $(window).width() and $(window).height() to get the size of the window, and then adapt the header container to that size.